# Select MIN(col) takes longer time than Select MAX(col)

Tags: database, db2

I am working in db2 database . I have around 247 IDs from which I have to find the minimum and maximum timestamp in different queries .
The Max query-
select max(timestamp) from mytable where rowid in(<247 IDs>)
Works fine and executes in about half minute

However the min query -
select min(timestamp) from mytable where rowid in(<247 IDs>)
Takes forever to execute .
I have indexes on  timestamp and rowid+timestamp

Why is the min query so long and how do I optimize because my applications UI is getting timeout before this min query can finish executing .the time out on UI cannot be changed

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at the both queries' execution plans? What did you see?

Comment: Am running in squirrel .. I don't think it has an execution plan

Comment: Squirrels sure don't have execution plans, at least they appear like they don't. Database engines, on the other hand, usually do; it's a matter of using the right tools to view them.